# Ansible - supply multiple ansible_become_pass=MYROOTPASSWORD

Tags: root, ansible, administration, ansible-2.x

I have 4 VM's which all have a different ssh users.

In order to use Ansible to manipulate the Vms I set my file `/etc/ansible/hosts` to this:

```
someserver1 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.121 ansible_ssh_port=222 ansible_ssh_user=someuser1 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass1
someserver2 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.122 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=someuser2 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass2
someserver3 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.123 ansible_ssh_port=222 ansible_ssh_user=someuser3 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass3
someserver4 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.124 ansible_ssh_port=222 ansible_ssh_user=someuser4 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass4
```

Lets say i have this playbook which only does an `ls` inside the `/root` folder:

```
- name: root access test
  hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: ls the root folder on my Vms
     become: yes
     become_user: root
     become_method: su
     command: chdir=/root ls -all
```

Using this call `ansible-playbook -v my-playbook.yml --extra-vars='ansible_become_pass=xxx-my-secret-root-password-for-someserver1'` i can become root on one of my machines but not on all.

**How is it possible to supply `somepass2`, `somepass3` and `somepass4`?**

Comment: Why not just put `ansible_become_pass` in line in the inventory like you already do with the SSH password? Or if they really are the same password then set an `all:vars` block to have `ansible_become_pass=ansible_ssh_pass`

Comment: Could you give examples for both? (Examples like write x into `hosts` and call `y` from bash?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just define `ansible_become_pass` as an in-line host variable in the inventory like you already have done with the SSH password? So your inventory would now look like this:

```
someserver1 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.121 ansible_ssh_port=222 ansible_ssh_user=someuser1 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass1 ansible_become_pass=somesudopass1
someserver2 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.122 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=someuser2 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass2 ansible_become_pass=somesudopass2
someserver3 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.123 ansible_ssh_port=222 ansible_ssh_user=someuser3 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass3 ansible_become_pass=somesudopass3
someserver4 ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.124 ansible_ssh_port=222 ansible_ssh_user=someuser4 ansible_ssh_pass=somepass4 ansible_become_pass=somesudopass4
```

Or, if your login password and sudo password are the same then simply add:

```
ansible_become_pass='{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}'
```

Either to an `all` group_vars file or in an in-line group vars block in the inventory file like this:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_become_pass='{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}'
```